# Cannot touch `/var/run/myfile/myfile.pid': Permission denied

Tags: linux, shell

The permissions for my `/var/run/myfile` are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 opentsdb opentsdb 2861 Nov  2 11:31 /etc/init.d/opentsdb
```

The script to run opentsdb contains the following line :

```
EDIT: 
$PID_FILE = myfile.pid
$TSD_USER = opentsdb

if start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$PID_FILE" \
--user "$TSD_USER" --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
>/dev/null; then   touch "$PID_FILE" &&  chown "$TSD_USER":"$TSD_GROUP" "$PID_FILE"

touch "$PID_FILE" && chown "$TSD_USER":"$TSD_GROUP" "$PID_FILE"
```

And on running the script i get this error :

```
touch: cannot touch `/var/run/myfile/myfile.pid': Permission denied
start-stop-daemon: unable to open myfile '/var/run/myfile/myfile.pid' for writing (Permission denied)
```

I have already done a

```
sudo chown opentsdb:opentsdb /var/run/myfile
```

and changed the user and the group to opentsdb 
 have also done a

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/run/myfile
```

and changed the permissions.

Do i need some special permission for `"touch"` command?

And as touch could not succeed myfile.pid is not created and myfile folder is empty!

EDIT:
On doing a sudo touch and sudo chown i could create the file but i do not want to run as sudo!

I am completely baffled here!

Comment: touch requires write privileges.

Comment: but why ? it is running "touch" as "openstdb" and opentsdb is the owner of the file. Why do I need to run as sudo ?

Comment: @Michael it should have write permission for user opentsdb and i am running it as user opentsdb

Comment: Your `ls -l` output says the owner is `my_process`, not `openstdb`.

Comment: Hey sorry i had edited guess i didnt get saved and i didnt notice . check now . srry about the error.

Comment: You say this is your run file but you are showing /etc/init.d/my_process `-rwxr-xr-x 1 opentsdb opentsdb 2861 Nov  2 11:31 /etc/init.d/my_process `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You don't need special permission for the touch command. Neither should you fiddle with the permissions of system directories, since this has security implications - as you found out.

Please make sure that

1. The script is executed with the effective userid `opentsdb`. [See the docs for details about setuid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid)
2. Please make sure that the upstart script is owned by user root and group root and set it's permissions to `0644`
3. Make sure `/var/run/myfile` is a directory by doing a
   `sudo rm -rf /var/run/myfile && sudo install -o opentsdb -m 0755 -d /var/run/mydir`
4. In case you are using upstart, edit your upstart script in **/etc/init** like shown below

   ```
   # You can omit 4 - it is a run level for custom use, but then...
   start on runlevel [345]
   # ... add it here
   stop on runlevel [0126]

   pre-start script
   # Sanitizing environment
   # The contents of var run are _not_ guaranteed to persist over reboot
   if [ ! -d /var/run/mydir ]
   then
     install -m 0755 -o opentsdb -d /var/run/mydir
   else
     chown opentsdb.opentsdb /var/run/mydir
     chmod 0755 /var/run/mydir
   fi

   # Remove stale pidfile if it exists
   # Note that if your process does not fork
   # this can be omitted, as upstart will keep track of
   # your processes pid automatically - same goes for the piddir.
   if [ -e /var/run/mydir/myfile.pid ]
   then
     rm /var/run/mydir/myfile.pid
   fi
   end script

   # Set this to the numeric uid for opentsdb
   # as shown in /etc/passwd
   setuid 1234

   # Same as for setuid, but for the primary group as it can be found
   # in /etc/group 
   setgid 1234

   # This is critical!
   # Read http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect _very carefully_
   # This one assumes that your process forks to background
   expect fork

   script
    # Do your stuff here - but don't fiddle with permissions
   end script
   ```

*(Please scroll the above...)*

Comment: permissions for my start script are  :                                   -rwxr-xr-x 1 opentsdb opentsdb 2876 Nov  2 12:23 opentsdb

Comment: why does this need to be owned by root?

Comment: Because root will execute it initially, sanitizing the environment and such and then it will drop it's root privileges and "become" user openwhatever to execute the actual process.

Comment: @joanOfArc: Frankly, I was assuming that you are using upstart with a current Linux distribution. This will not work with older versions and very new ones (RHEL derivates >= 7 use systemd, Debianish ones will in the future). Please let me know, I'll adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the user before trying to do the touch -- I'm assuming that you do not want your process to run as root.

`...
   su - $TSD_USER && touch "$PID_FILE" 
...`

I do something similar for running Tomcat

`...
RETVAL=0
start(){
   echo "Author: Modified from Brandon Klimek's script "
   echo "URL: http://blog.sixthpoint.com/tomcat-service-script/ "
   echo "Starting Tomcat 7: "
   su - $TOMCAT_USER -c "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh"
   RETVAL=$?
   echo
   [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $LOCKFILE
   return $RETVAL
}
...`

HTH